# Python memory of list in "for" loop

Tags: python, list, memory

Using some function I create a list of million items within and check memory consumption

```
print ('Memory at start: {0} Mb'.format(memory_usage_psutil()))
my_list = people_list(1000000)
print ('Memory at end: {0} Mb'.format(memory_usage_psutil()))
```

What I get is:

```
Memory at start: 100.90625 Mb
Memory at end: 403.8125 Mb
```

So creating a list and keeping it in memory takes ~300Mb.

For example I want to count amount of items in **PART** of `my_list` **WITHOUT** using `len()`

```
count = 0
additional_list = my_list[0:500000]
for item in additional_list:
    count += 1
    if count == 499999:
        print ('Memory in loop: {0} Mb'.format(memory_usage_psutil()))
```

and results confused me.

```
Memory at start: 100.90625 Mb
Memory in loop: 403.6953125 Mb
Memory at end: 403.6953125 Mb
```

I expected that creating additional list will increase memory consumption by 150Mb but it did not happen. Can you explain why? I mean id's are different

```
In [30]: id(my_list)
Out[30]: 2672641621704

In [31]: id(additional_list)
Out[31]: 2672642905864
```

and same results come from:

```
for item in my_list[0:500000]:
    count += 1
    if count == 499999:
        print ('Memory in loop: {0} Mb'.format(memory_usage_psutil()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that your two lists are different objects and have different addresses in memory.  However, the individual objects in the list are the same.  Using a slice basically gave you a view on some elements in your list.

You can confirm that with::

```
>>> map(id, my_list)[0:500000] == map(id, additional_list)
```

Comment: The list still contains 500000 addresses to those objects which should cost at least a few MB.

Comment: Your last example fails for me. In fact `map(id, some_list) == map(id, some_list)` is *always* `False` given that you are creating two different `map` objects.

Comment: @Bakuriu `map` does not give you a `map object`, it is a python `list` of `long`, which the `==` operator will compare by contents.  You might have ``map`` overshadowed by something else in your shell?

Comment: `>>> map(id, [1,2,3])
<map object at 0x7f6f6b384a58>` You are probably using an outdated version of python.

Comment: @Bakuriu indeed, I'm using outdated python2, I didn't realise `map` is lazy in python3, but that explains why `==` is `False` in your version and `True` in mine :-D